# Wagering System

Tags: solidity

I have a multiplayer game I created in Unity and I would like to add a betting system to it with a smart contract. There will be 4 players and only one winner. I only want to allow for 0.1 Eth betting and have only one winner. I would also like 2% to go to a dev wallet. Could someone help me with this? I'm not good at creating smart contracts.

Comment: To reiterate: Each player would bet 0.1 Eth and it would get sent to the contract and then 0.002 sent to the dev wallet. Upon winning the player would be able to claim the .392 Eth. I have an SDK working with Unity I just don't know how to make the contract.

Comment: Hello TyeBeach! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! This site is for technical questions about Ethereum and related technologies. If you are looking for a partnership or hiring contractors r/EthDev and LinkedIn are better places.